# Adding custom fonts in react webpack packaging

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, custom-font

I'm creating a reactJs component as a package to publish in npmjs. I have added custom fonts as tff files through webpack and those fonts are applied in the webpack development mode. But those fonts are not applying in the webpack production though those tff files are included in the final build folder. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

To add .ttf fonts in my actual project, I use this rule in both webpack files (dev & build)

```
{
  test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
  use: [
   {
     loader: 'file-loader',
     options: {
       limit: 10_000,
       mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
     },
   },
  ],
},
```